# Set the alt text value for images in PowerPoint via AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint

I want to run an AppleScript a bit like this:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    repeat with tSlide in (get slides of active presentation)
        repeat with tPic in (get pictures of tSlide)
            set is_decorative of tPic to true
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

But `set is_decorative of tPic to true` doesn't work and I don't know the correct incantation.

Even better would be able to set the "alt text" value for each image by popping up a dialog box showing the pic and asking the user for it when the script it runs.

Are these properties accessible via AppleScript? Could it be done on Windows, or otherwise in some programmatic way?

Comment: RE: "I don't know the correct incantation." -- Did you not cut the head off of a chicken and drink its blood while running the script? Sorry, I just couldn't resist. If I had PowerPoint I'd help, but alas I use a Mac so I don't have to use anything Microsoft.

Comment: I've posted Microsoft's AppleScript for Office for Mac reference PDFs, feel free to download them: http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2020/10/office-applescript-reference-cool-code/

Answer (score 1):

I just cobbled up a bit of VBA on a Windows version of PPT (2016 in this case).

For each picture in the active presentation, it asks the user for alt text for the picture; if they provide alt text, it assigns it. If they enter a blank or delete any alt text that's already there, it sets the image as decorative.

I haven't tested it on the Mac, but it should work there as well.

```
Sub SetPicsDecorative()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oSl As Slide

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
If oSh.Type = msoPicture Then

' Here's the meat of the thing
' Ask the user for Alt text
oSh.AlternativeText = InputBox("Enter alt text or press ENTER to skip:", _
    "Alt text for " & oSh.Name, oSh.AlternativeText)

' If they didn't enter any alt text, assume that the image is decorative
If Len(oSh.AlternativeText) = 0 Then
    oSh.Decorative = True
End If

End If  ' msoPicture
Next
Next

End Sub
```